# PHP Values not updating with AJAX Post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have the need to receive javascript variables in PHP so I set up my Ajax call and script, I have verified that AJAX is sending back the proper response it just seems like server side is not wanting to actually pull the information. Here is my javascript

```
$("#payments2").on("change", function() {

    $("#p1").val($(this).find("option:selected").text());

    var Id = $(this).find("option:selected").attr('value');
    var Ids = $("#payments").find("option:selected").attr('value');

    $.post("postit.php", { 
        Id: Id,
        Ids: Ids
    }, function(data){

    var theResult = data;
    }, 'json' );
});
$("#exchange").on("change", function() {
    var am = $(this).attr('value');
    var fee = $("#fee").attr('value');
    var cost = $("#cost").attr('value');
    var perc = fee / 100;
    var tot = perc * am;
    var total = am - tot - cost;

    $("#return").val(total);
});
```

and here is my PHP variable call

```
<li>
    <label for="exchange">Amount to Exchange</label>
    <input type="text" id="exchange" name="exchange" maxlength="100">
    <span>Amount to Exchange</span>
</li>
<?php
$amounts = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `exchange` WHERE `fromp` = '".$_POST['fromp']."' AND `top` = '".$_POST['top']."'");
$amo = $amounts->fetch_assoc();
?>
<input type="hidden" id="fee" name="fee" value="<?php echo $amo['fee'] ?>" />
<input type="hidden" id="cost" name="pay" value="<?php echo $amo['cost'] ?>" />
<li>
    <label for="return">Amount to Receive</label>
    <input type="text" id="return" name="return" maxlength="100" value="">
    <span>Amount you will receive</span>
</li>
```

Since I can clearly tell that my Ajax call is sending back the proper information and I am not getting any errors in my query then I am unsure as to why my values for `fees` and `cost` aren't changing causing me to receive `NaN` in my `return` text box.

Here is also the contents of my `postit.php` file

```
  $Id= isset($_POST['Id']) ? $_POST['Id'] : '';
  $Ids= isset($_POST['Ids']) ? $_POST['Ids'] : '';
  include "connect.php";
     $que = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `exchange` WHERE `fromp` = '".$Ids."' AND `top` = '".$Id."'");

    /* Get query results */

    $results = $que->fetch_assoc();

    /* Send back to client */

    echo json_encode($results);
    exit;
```

This is my first time using posting variables from javascript to php so I am sure I have done something wrong, or maybe there is a way to get the information that was passed by the script using javascript, perhaps a way to get the variables I need within my javascript function rather than the mysql query?

Comment: can you alert(total); ?

Comment: @JulioSoares it gives me `NaN`

Comment: How it is connected with ajax? Where is `payments2` field? What should happen and what really happens?

Comment: @u_mulder `$.post("postit.php", { 
        Id: Id,
        Ids: Ids
    }, function(data){

    var theResult = data;
    }, 'json' );` is my Ajax call, the `payments2` field is right above the `exchange` field it is a select box, when it changes it runs the code above. It is supposed to allow me to pull my rates from the database, which it DOES send back in JSON format but I have no idea how to take that data and post it back into by fields.

Comment: Use `.val` to get the values of fields. e.g. `var am = $(this).val();`

Comment: @Musa that solves the `NaN` issue, but it is counting `fee` and `cost` as 0 and it shouldn't be

Comment: I don't know if you realize this but you in no way modify the fee and cost fields. Your ajax creates new html that has no bearing on the current page.

Comment: @Musa I am not sure how, when it is sending back information in JSON, I should be able to pull that information back into my form, I am sure there is a way it is just I am going about it wrong, like I said above I think I need to get the JSON information using javascript instead of trying to get it using PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not setting the values for the fields from your json response, try

```
$.post("postit.php", { 
    Id: Id,
    Ids: Ids
}, function(data){

    $("#fee").val(data['fee']);
    $("#cost").val(data['cost']);

}, 'json' );
```

Comment: Thank you Musa, I am not sure why I couldn't figure this out myself, but I will thank you a million more times because I was starting to get a headache from it all.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm missing something, but your jQuery is sending 'Id' and 'Ids' as the form data, and the PHP is trying to use 'fromp' and 'top'.

Additionally, it doesn't appear that your response handler is doing anything with the DOM. Have you inspected the Network panel of your chrome debugger to see what the PHP script is responding with?

Comment: That is because when it is sent back with JSON keys of 'fromp' and 'top' I do use the debugger though, that is how I can see that the Ajax call to the script is indeed sending the JSON keys and values back. Basically I guess I don't know how to parse JSON, I have only worked with it twice.. any suggestions on what I should do. I have searched for answers but can't seem to find anything that is helpful